# Try Catch Statement not Raised -- Null exception raised instead of code in Catch exception

Tags: vb.net, try-catch

Just upgraded to Visual Studio 2022 from Visual Studio 2012 and the Try/Catch statements in the application do not work. System.Null Reference exception is raised when a null value is entered. It is supposed to show a message box when that happens. Works fine in Visual Studio 2012. The application is a Visual Basic application.

Try

```
        Me.Clients_SourcecodesTableAdapter.ClearBeforeFill = False
        Me.Clients_SourcecodesTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DataSet1.Clients_Sourcecodes, Me.ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString)

        'frmmarketingsearchle.Clients_SourcecodesTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DataSet1.Clients_Sourcecodes, Me.ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString)

        Me.Label2.Text = "The Total Record Count for Your Selection is " & Me.DataSet1.Clients_Sourcecodes.Rows.Count.ToString

        strSourcecode = (Me.ListBox1.SelectedItem)
        Me.ListBox1.Items.Remove(strSourcecode)
        Me.ListBox2.Items.Add(strSourcecode)
        Me.DataSet1.AcceptChanges()
        If Me.ListBox1.Items.Count > 0 Then
            Me.ListBox1.SelectedItem = Me.ListBox1.Items(0)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception

        MessageBox.Show("You did not select a list to add. Please select a list to add")
        Me.ListBox1.Focus()
    End Try
```

Comment: Please remove the vb6 tag from your question. VB6 and vb.net are completely different and that code is vb.net.

Comment: In order for the exception to be caught, it must be thrown, so saying that the exception is thrown is not saying anything. Are you saying, without actually saying, that the debugger breaks when the exception is thrown? If so then that is due to the IDE settings specifying that it should break on that type of exception. You can specify that that should not happen in the exception settings. Is the expected message displayed if you don't run the project in the debugger?

Comment: Catching `Exception` is generally bad practice. If you expect a specific type of exception then catch that type. Otherwise, you may be masking the throwing of an unexpected type of exception and thus a bug in your code. Also, catching a `NullReferenceException` is generally bad too. If something might be `Nothing`, check for `Nothing` before using it.